# JavaScript and jQuery only needed for certain pages

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a C#, MVC website, I want to have all JavaScript/jQuery needed for the site to be contained in one file, but some of the JavaScript/jQuery is only needed on certain pages.

Example, Currently in the JavaScript file, I have code like the following -

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myId').click(function () {
        doCoolStuff();
    });

});
```

The above statement is executed on every page, but it is only needed on one. What is the best way to have JavaScript/jQuery run only on the page (or pages) that need it?

Comment: Remove it from the file that your whole website uses and put it in the file where you want to use it

Comment: Why do you want your JS in only 1 file? You will have a file of hundreds of lines, with lots of difficulties for maintaining it.

Comment: The site may have 10 pages and each page may need some JavaScript that only applies to it. So I could have ten files (which doesn't sound good). Is it bad to have JavaScript that only applies to one or two pages executed on every page?

Comment: The javascript that is used everywhere can go to a "main.js". Then, if you have specific functionnalities, a good way would be to put them in separate files. That way, you would be able to locate your functions faster, and also will be able to re-use them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Section`s to include items when they are necessary, and make it unrequired (but included when it's present).

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
@* ... *@
@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
@* ... *@
```

**SomeView.cshtml**

```
@* ... *@
@section Scripts
{
    @* direct inclusion *@
    <script>
        $(function(){
            // your code here
        });
    </script>

    @* or file reference *@
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/alternate.script.js")"></script>
}
@* ... *@
```

Comment: I _really_ wish people that down-voted had a backbone and supplied a reason.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be an answer to the question. The guy only wants 1 file containing all his javascript. (Although,  I would do it the way you answered)

Comment: He doesn't want the single file to contain his javascript but include his javascript on a single page.

Comment: I want to have all JavaScript/jQuery needed for the site to be contained in one file. I thought that this was a standard way to do things. No?

Comment: "I really wish people that down-voted had a backbone and supplied a reason." <- this! Thanks for the answer Brad!